# autosuggest - to activate key board arrow to view the list

Tags: javascript, keyboard, autosuggest

http://localapartmentdeals.com/

on the above site there is a location bar and if you type any state (US) it will display an autosuggest list but it will not allow key board strokes to select the list,

eg: no down arrow is working there.

any help please

thanks
deve

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look the arrow keys are detected, you have to implement it.

You should have somewhere in the `function suggest` a code that handle the arrow keys like:

```
...
switch(keyCode) {
    case 38: 
        //up arrow, highlight previous entry
        break;
    case 40: //down arrow 
        //up arrow, highlight next entry
        break;
    ...
}
```